# Cannot convert from utf16be to utf8

Tags: shell-script, aix, character-encoding

I'm working on a script for aix 7.2 and I'm getting an error when I try to convert from `utf16be` to `utf8`.

I'm using `iconv` to convert. Using the follow the script:

```
for file in *.OPEN
do
    echo "Converting file $file"
    iconv -f utf16be  -t utf8 < "$file" > "${file}.UTF8"
done
echo "Conversion of all files to UTF-8 done!"
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
iconv: 0791-004 cannot open converter
```

Comment: Seemingly related: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1767097

Comment: Is the conversion name correct? `iconv -f help` I think...

Answer (score 3):

If you install GNU `iconv` package, the following command will work:

```
/opt/freeware/bin/iconv -f utf-16be  -t utf-8
```

Otherwise try this:

```
/usr/bin/iconv -f ucs-2  -t utf-8
```